# isolating an angularjs anonymous $parser:ueoe error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Having a devil of time finding where this error is coming from.

On a button, I have `ng-click="goUrl('L_1001_1008_1113')"`

In the controller (ClubCtrl) is:

```
$scope.goUrl = function(id) {
   console.log("HereA - "+id) ;
   $location.url('/tab/clubs/'+id) ;
   console.log("HereB - "+id) ;
}
```

When I click the button I get this error in console:

> HereA - L_1001_1008_1113
>
> HereB - L_1001_1008_1113
>
> ionic.bundle.js:20306 Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of
>   expression: club.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$parse/ueoe?p0=club.
>
> ```
> at ionic.bundle.js:8762
> at Parser.consume (ionic.bundle.js:20747)
> at Parser.identifier (ionic.bundle.js:20778)
> at Parser.fieldAccess (ionic.bundle.js:20975)
> at Parser.primary (ionic.bundle.js:20701)
> at Parser.unary (ionic.bundle.js:20970)
> at Parser.multiplicative (ionic.bundle.js:20953)
> at Parser.additive (ionic.bundle.js:20944)
> at Parser.relational (ionic.bundle.js:20935)
> at Parser.equality (ionic.bundle.js:20926)
> ```

There is only one place I use `club` - its in the `detail-club.html` template page and in that pages  controller (`ClubDetailCtrl`).  My state changer is:

```
  .state('tab.clubs', {
      cache: true,
      url: '/clubs',
      params: {
        'refreshClubs' : 0,
        'pushAction' : 0,
        'pushSub' : null,
        'pushMsg' : null,
        'pushCode' : null
      },
      views: {
        'tab-clubs': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-clubs.html',
          controller: 'ClubCtrl'

        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.club-detail', {
      url: '/clubs/:ceID',
      views: {
        'tab-clubs': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/detail-clubs.html',
          controller: 'ClubDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

At the moment, I have commented out EVERYTHING in `ClubDetailCtrl` rxcept a `console.log("HereC");` trying to isolate the error.  But "HereC" never fires in the console.  So I know the issue isn't happening in `ClubDetailCtrl`.

The error message is terrible and doesn't point to whats actually triggering it.  What is this error and more importantly how can I track it down?

Could the error becoming FROM the template page that has the button in it?  Or could it becoming from the template page the button is trying to redirect to?  the redirect page/controller is the only thing with just `club` in it, but I imagine the controller console message `HereC` would fire before a template page would cause the error.  So where else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purpose, create a simplified template and controller for the state:

```
.state('tab.club-detail', {
  url: '/clubs/:ceID',
  views: {
    'tab-clubs': {
      template: `<div>DETAIL-CLUBS</div>`,
      controller: function() {
          console.log("details controller init");
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I finally found it.  Posted below.  The anonymous error though had me looking at the source ng-click, the `.state` and the source template controller - NOT in the template page to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 2 days I finally found the error.  Posting this in case someone else finds themselves dealing with a similar situation.

I had added new HTML to the template page the above link/url is loading.  The new HTML code was supposed to print out a readable description by referencing `{{club.}}` - apparently I didn't add all the code, it was supposed to be `{{club.ceDesc}}` - this was causing the error to be thrown, no page was loading, no other indication this was where the error was coming from.  It appeared the error was being thrown on the ng-click from the prevoius page or in the `.state.` url call .

Comment: Looks the error message was right. Unexpected end of expresson: `club.` The AngularJS parser doesn't like dots at the end of an expression. The JavaScript parser doesn't like it either.

Comment: I don't disagree...but trying to find where it was coming from was a nightmare.  Wish Angulars parse error info was more specific.